# How to compare 2 Lists and add text in Python

Tags: python

I have 2 Lists. 1 contains my predictions, the other the actual results. I want to replace the values in 'mypicks' to 1 if it is in list 'winners; and 0 if the value is not in list 'winners'.

Using the 2 lists below. 'mypicks' would change to **[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]**
0 represent value NOT in list 'winners' and 1 represents values that ARE in list 'winners'.

```
winners: ['GB', 'Ten', 'SF', 'Ari', 'Dal', 'Bal', 'Was', 'KC', 'Buf', 'LA', 'NE', 'Cin', 'Min', 'Oak', 'Hou']
mypicks: ['Atl', 'Mia', 'Ten', 'KC', 'Phi', 'Det', 'Dal', 'TB', 'Pit', 'Den']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mypicks_binary = [1 if item in winners else 0 for item in mypicks]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[int(item in winners) for item in mypicks]
```

If you're trying to use this for checking purposes, then get rid of `int` so you have convenient Booleans.  Either way, if you only need to count the quantity of correct picks, simply `sum` on that list will get the desired total.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `pandas` tag is correct on this question:

```
correct_picks = list(df['mypicks'].isin(df['winners']).astype(int))
```

Will return a list of [0,1] like you're looking for, in `pandas` columns instead of lists.